# Populate text boxes with data based on redirect from another page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, gridview

This task is a little out of my reach so i dont even really know where to start...

I want a user to click the command field "select" in my gridview.  I then want them to be redirected (  `response.redirect()`) to an input form that will have its various asp.net text boxes filled with data from that selected item.

I also need the ability to do this logical process:

> IF the form is loaded from user
>   selecting item in gridview THEN
>       ''Populate controls with data from selected gridview item   Else  Load
>   form as normal and have the controls
>   blank endif

I was suggested to use this command for the redirect load...Not sure if its correct:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If InStr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"), "LogViewer.aspx") Then
            'FILL the text boxes with the data from data source!
        End If
    End Sub
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
EDIT

I got it working thanks to A Tuliper...now how can i get my drop down list to select the correct item based on the data in the gridview??

```
Private Sub getData(ByVal user As String)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("My Connection ")
    connection.Open()
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * from AppMaster WHERE RecNum = @recnum", connection)
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recnum", user)
    sqlDa.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        NameTxt.Text = dt.Rows(0)("UserName").ToString()
         '''''''''this drop down list needs to be the correct item'''''''''''''''''
        'AppDropDownList.SelectedValue = dt.Rows("Application").ToString()
        SelectedDateTxt.Text = dt.Rows(0)("DateOfChange").ToString()
        DescriptionTxt.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Description").ToString()
        SnipetTxt.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Snippet").ToString()

    End If
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest unhacky method here is to simply create a link in your gridview with the parameters in the URL going to say:

```
<a href="/YourSecondPage.aspx?param1=xx&param2=yyyy">Details</a>
```

And then in your second page read them:

```
string param1 = Request.QueryString["Param1"]; //or whatever its called - change it of course
```